# CBLQueryEnumerator count returns nil for first time, second time works correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view, nosql

when I launch App for first time (App is not installed perviously) on simulator, the instance of CBLQueryEnumerator count returns nil.

I found it by placing breakpoints and executing

```
po enumeratorResult
```

but the enumerator object seems to be allocated.

When I launch App for second time (in this case App is already installed on simulator) the instance of CBLQueryEnumerator count returns 5 (I have 5 documents in DB).

Am I making mistake in using CBLQuery or CBLQueryEnumerator please guide me correct.

**viewContoller.m**

```
@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.progressView.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleBar;
    [self.progressView setProgress:2.5 animated:YES];
    self.cbObject = [CouchBaseObject sharedInstance];

    self.syncURLLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.cbObject.syncURL];
    self.documentList = [NSMutableArray array];


    [self addDocumentToTicketModel:self.cbObject.database];

    if(self.cbObject.pull.status == kCBLReplicationOffline || self.cbObject.pull.status != kCBLReplicationActive){
        [self performSelector:@selector(pushTicketDetailViewController) withObject:self afterDelay:2.5];
    }


}

-(void)addDocumentToTicketModel:(CBLDatabase*)database{
    CBLView* view = [database viewNamed:@"_temp_view"];

    if (!view.mapBlock) {
    [view setMapBlock:MAPBLOCK({
        if (doc) {
            emit(doc,@"1");
        }
    })version:@"1.0"];
}

CBLQuery* query = [view createQuery];

[query runAsync:^(CBLQueryEnumerator * enumeratorResult, NSError * error) {
    if(!error){
        for (CBLQueryRow* row in enumeratorResult) {
            CBLDocument* document = [database documentWithID:row.documentID];
            Ticket* ticket = [Ticket modelForDocument:document];
            NSLog(@"Ticket ; %@",ticket.propertiesToSave);
            [self.documentList addObject:ticket];
        }
    }
}];
}
@end
```

**CouchBaseObject.m**

```
@implementation CouchBaseObject

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        NSError* error;
        self.manager = [CBLManager sharedInstance];
        if(!self.manager){
            NSLog(@"manager fail");
            return nil;
        }
        self.database = [self.manager databaseNamed:@"couch_sample_one" error:&error];
        if(!self.database){
            NSLog(@"database fail");
            return nil;
        }
        [self initReplication];
    }
    return self;
}

+(CouchBaseObject*)sharedInstance{
    static CouchBaseObject* sharedInstance = nil;
    if(sharedInstance == nil){
        sharedInstance = [[CouchBaseObject alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)initReplication{
    self.syncURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://***.***.***.***:5984/couch_sample_one"];
    self.pull = [self.database createPullReplication:self.syncURL];
    self.push = [self.database createPushReplication:self.syncURL];
    self.pull.continuous = NO;
    self.push.continuous = NO;
    [self startReplication];
}

-(void)startReplication{
    [self.push start];
    [self.pull start];
}

-(void)stopReplication{
    [self.push stop];
    [self.pull stop];
}
@end
```

For first time the control will not enter into `for in` loop

```
for (CBLQueryRow* row in result)
```

and for second time control will be in that loop.

This also happens when on just on launch.

Scenario.

1. Run App (Freshly installed app)
2. Navigate from initialViewController to viewController.
3. First time control does not enter into for loop, `CBLQueryEnumerator Object.count returns nil`.
4. pop to initialViewController
5. Push viewController, but this time controls enter into `for in` loop and `CBLQueryEnumerator object.count returns 5`

Hierarchy (Push).
*initialViewContoller -> ViewContoller -> ListViewController*

Comment: Hey I figured out problem. For first time as you can see line of code`self.cbObject = [CouchBaseObject sharedInstance];` which initiates the replication n at the same time just with difference of nanoseconds I m trying to download the data using `-(void)addDocumentToTicketModel:(CBLDatabase*)database` method, here the case was happening is, I was trying to fetch data before data is available in local CouchDB. For second time data is successfully replicated, and data is available for fetching.

Comment: To make it work properly for me, I used notification `kCBLReplicationChangeNotification`. I am checking the status `if(self.cbObject.pull.status == kCBLReplicationStopped)`, If that evaluates to **true** then I m fetching data, because not data is available in database and I m allowed to fetch data,

**Caution** : *I m just working with pull replication for now, In future I will add push replication too.*

Thank You.

Comment: Please leave comment if anyone need new updated code.